# Run automation Tests for android version 7.0 real device

Tags: android, mobile, automation, appium

I have a question that can we run automation tests for hybrid mobile application on a real device android version 7.0 using Appium version 1.5.3(Ara) or 1.4.16.1?

what is the compatibility of android version of these Appium versions?

if anyone knows the answer please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have used both the versions of appium for all Android versions(Android 5.0, Android 6.0, Android 7.0).

**I can say 1.5.3 is better than 1.4. (There are lot of enhancements in 1.5.3)**

If you are automating hybrid mobile application there is one more advantage to identify the elements in WebView. You don't need to switch your driver to webView. You can directly search them without switching to webview. The new automator has built-in capability to identify the element inside webview.

**Elements from webview can be directly identified on real device with Android version 6.0+**

I hope this helps.